How can i implement export functionality for the angular material table into csv format?
Earlier version of angular almost worked with MatExporter but currently in angular 17, this module has been deprecated and i am facing issues.
Is there any other library to use for exporting into other document formats?
i know i can get it done with simple hard code but i want to use library to ease the situation.

try using xlsx latest 0.18.5, it works for me on 17 and 18. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
